# Make the click-button code not disappear instantly?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this html form, with 2 input fields, username and password. After I click the button, I want a message to say at the top of the form: "Invalid username or password" if it is wrong, or "Successful" if it is ok, instead of "Login required".
The problem is, when I click, I get the message, but only for a fraction of a second, then it goes back to "Login required".
How can I make it stay there?

HTML:

```
        <div id="chat">           
            <form>
                <div> 
                    Login required
                </div>
                <input type="text" id="username" placeholder="username">
                <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="password">
                <button>Authenticate</button>
            </form>
        </div>
```

JS:

```
$('#chat form button').click(function(){
    var msg= $('#chat form div');
    var user = document.getElementById("username").value;
    var pass = document.getElementById("password").value;
    
    if(user == "admin" && pass == "admin1234")
        msg.html("Successful");

    else
        msg.html("Invalid username or password");

    })
```

I tried with both .click and .submit functions, but same result.

Comment: Submit buttons submit the form

Comment: I highly suggest you use curly braces for your if/else statements. Particularly if you're new to JS and don't understand the nuances of NOT using them.

Comment: Prevent the default behavior of the button. When there is only one button without an input type, it becomes a submit button.